# Know if Instance returned by Registry Key is Default or Named instance

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have this piece of code:

```
        List<SQLInstancia> list = new List<SQLInstancia>();
        SQLInstancia instancia;
        int cont = 0;
        RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
        using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
        {
            //Instancias en 64bits
            RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);
            //instancias en 32bits
            RegistryKey instanceKey_ = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server", false);
            if (instanceKey != null)
            {

                foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    cont++;
                    instancia = new SQLInstancia();
                    instancia.Nombre = Environment.MachineName + "\\" + instanceName;
                    instancia.IdInstancia = cont;
                    list.Add(instancia);
                }
            }
        }
```

With that code I'm getting all of the SQL Server instances running in my local machine, but the thing is that I can't know if it's a default instance or a Named instance.

I've allready tried with SMO and with SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources(), the second one worked, but it retrieves all of the instances on the network, and I don't need them, I just need the ones that are on the local machine. With SMO it shows my Named instance, but won't show the default instance.